# How to customize a TimePickerDialog?

Tags: android, dialog, timepicker

I'm looking to create something EXACTLY like TimePickerDialog (look and feel) in Android, but it would be for MINUTES/SECONDS, not HOURS/MINUTES. Therefore AM/PM would not be relevant and would therefore allow MINUTE to be greater than 24 (making the max 59).

Is it possible to change the TimePickerDialog instance in any way to reflect this?

Any and all suggestions would be greatly appreciated. :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is it possible to change the TimePickerDialog instance in any way to reflect this?

No, but the [layout](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/res/res/layout/time_picker_dialog.xml;h=d5a6b5eb9bc1725b8fa6d938b25a06f3b94c67aa;hb=HEAD) and [source code](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/java/android/app/TimePickerDialog.java;h=a04b9e94405b62b966382f3607342883d802d703;hb=HEAD) to `TimePickerDialog` are both available as a starting point for implementing your own dialog.

Comment: Great; this helped a lot! I landed up implementing my own NumberPicker which I got from TimePickerDialog. :-)

Comment: Honestly, I didn't even know where to find this, so thank you for the link!

Comment: I keep getting...This webpage is not available
The connection to android.git.kernel.org was interrupted...any ideas why?

Comment: @easycheese: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7294796/access-denied-to-android-git-kernel-org/7295506#7295506

Comment: Links have changed: [layouts](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/res/layout/) and [sources](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/app), I'm only giving the directory because there are multiple files of interest.

Answer (score 1):

This might help:

TimePicker with seconds:

https://github.com/IvanKovac/TimePickerWithSeconds

Have a look.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As the links in CommonsWare's answer are now dead, you might want to know that the source for TimePickerDialog is probably already on your local machine - it is included in the SDK.  Try looking in the following locations:

```
[SDK_HOME]/sources/android-23/android/app/TimePickerDialog.java
or
[SDK_HOME]/sources/android-23/com/android/datetimepicker/time/TimePickerDialog.java


[SDK_HOME]/platforms/android-23/data/res/layout/time_picker_dialog.xml
```

Of course, choose the Android version that you want to borrow from.  References to R. should be to android.R.  Unfortunately, there seem to be some [visibility issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30289297/cant-access-datepicker-validationcallback-in-my-code) with ValidationCallback - even on recent SDK levels.