# Access denied to android.git.kernel.org

Tags: linux, kernel, android-source

Anyone know why I have no trouble accessing the projects on http://git.kernel.org but cannot access http://android.git.kernel.org ?

I've also tried an SSL connection to android.git.kernel.org to no avail.

Anyone else having a similar issue or know what might be up?  The only thing I can think of is that the site is down but I have nothing to back that up with.

Comment: There was a kernel.org hack a few days ago. So it's still down. See the news you can access from kernel.org directly for more info.

Comment: You should remove your question though, it won't be useful in the future.

Comment: @Kheldar - if people keep removing these questions, they'll keep turning up as long as the site remains down.

Comment: I'm aware of the kernel.org hack, but I didn't think that was the reason because I could still access all of the other parts of kernel.org.

Comment: @Randaltor - the android part is likely not maintained by the same people.

Comment: @Kheldar - answers in the form of alternate sources could be of lasting interest, as the temporary situations demonstrates that there may be an over-reliance on a single source.

Comment: @Kheldar - I didn't realize I couldn't use this site to ask a time sensitive question.  I appreciate that heavy users of this site might get tired of seeing them.  Before I posted, I considered this but thought that the answers posted would provide some insight about the problem that would not be time sensitive (like the one MizardX posted about the forum).

If you could let me know what the acceptable minimum bound is for a question's expected utility, I'd be happy to know.

Comment: I really cannot tell you, but I guess http://meta.stackoverflow.com/ is the place to search for this information.

Answer (score 3):

> Anyone know why I have no trouble accessing the projects on http://git.kernel.org but cannot access http://android.git.kernel.org ?

The core Android team is [still inspecting the damage from the kernel.org hack attack](https://groups.google.com/group/android-contrib/msg/642c6280e2350325).

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to look at the source, you can access it at [Code Aurora Forum](http://www.codeaurora.org/). Click on Android → (G).