# Is there a working public mirror of android.git.kernel.org?

Tags: android-source

[Sorry for the dumb question.  This has *got* to be a FAQ the past few days, but I can't find anything other than people complaining that the repo is down and to check the news...]

I have been unable to use repo to access http://android.git.kernel.org for a while now; obviously this is due to the attack on kernel.org.  Unfortunately, I need to pull down versions of the source tree I do not already have.

I know that at least some of the packages are mirrored on http://github.com/android, but the manifest file needs to edited (to, e.g., replace / with _) and it doesn't appear to have all of them anyway.  Surely there's a better way?

Comment: Do you have a previous version cloned somewhere on your machines? You could always point to them until the servers are back up again. :)

Comment: Well, I do... repo sucks them all down automatically, right?  Unfortunately the source is a mess of tons of different individual git packages, so I wasn't keen on manually extracting the various versions using git.  Can repo be coerced into using the local clones to pull the branches?

Comment: Hm. I am afraid I don't know. I thought it would be a simple search/replace.

Comment: If you are contributing to the code base, you might try the `android-contrib` Google Group, or search its recent archives.

Answer (score 7):

https://www.codeaurora.org/gitweb/quic/la/

Source: [Access denied to android.git.kernel.org](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7294796/access-denied-to-android-git-kernel-org/7294862#7294862)

Answer (score 3):

Google finally has an own mirror online that seems to work:
https://android.googlesource.com
https://source.android.com/source/downloading.html

Answer (score 0):

http://218.211.38.204/

This is Chih-Wei Huang's personal mirror.