# Android: Easiest way to download source code

Tags: android

I am having difficulty downloading the Android source code using the recommended instructions, due to problems with Repo, Cygwin, Python etc (See other topic I've open)

Therefore, I'm wondering is there an easier way to download the source code for a specific SDK version?

For example I'd like to take a look at the AlertDialog.Builder class without having to download everything.

Thanks

Comment: Try this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7311858/is-there-a-working-public-mirror-of-android-git-kernel-org

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/449763/where-can-i-browse-android-source-code-on-line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to see the Java code, you can use GrepCode. For example, [AlertDialog.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/app/AlertDialog.java).

Comment: I'd also recommend this plugin I found on one of the other threads for Eclipse. Very useful: http://www.androidpolice.com/2011/12/22/gold-for-android-developers-add-aosp-source-code-to-eclipse-with-the-android-sources-plugin/