# Why does repo command fail to find android.git.kernel.org and how do I get work around the failure if I cannot upgrade repo?

Tags: repo

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7903808/1666926) points to the new `repo` command. The `repo` command points to the old site in older versions of repo. I have a shared Ubuntu 16 system where I was hesitant to update the `repo` command. How can point `repo` to the migrated `repo` at https://android.googlesource.com?

Answer (score 0):

`repo` is just a Python script which has the correct url in the version I have on Ubuntu 18. Thus, a simple workaround is to just modify the URL in your script.

The failure is apparently a result of `repo` looking for its own repository so it can report if your current version is out of date (maybe it is used for other things?). My newer version of `repo` sets the URL differently:

1. The script looks for an environment variable named `REPO_URL` which, if set, overrides the location. If the variable is set, the script just uses it.
2. If the variable is not set, the script sets `REPO_URL = 'https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo'`