# Can't access DatePicker.ValidationCallback in my code

Tags: java, android, datepicker, android-widget

I have a simple DatePickerFragment that extends DialogFragment.  I'm wanting to set a validation callback so I can prevent "OK" being selected if an invalid date is picked.  I first tried setMaxDate and that grays out the invalid choices but still allows them to be selected and OK to be pressed.  So I was hoping setting the validation callback would be the solution.

```
abstract public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    public DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog;

  //  public DatePickerFragment() {
  //
  //  }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
        DatePicker datePicker = datePickerDialog.getDatePicker();
        datePicker.setMaxDate(c.getTimeInMillis());

        // this won't resolve!
        datePicker.setValidationCallback( xxx );

        return datePickerDialog;
    }

}
```

I cannot figure out why I can't access or reference android.widget.DatePicker.ValidationCallback or any of the related bits in my code.  If I hit CTRL+B to look at DatePickerDialog I can see it imports it and references these fields.  Everything appears to be public.  But I can't even get the import to resolve.  What could be wrong?  This is a brand new install of the latest Android Studio and my gradle file looks like this:

```
dependencies {
    // Include local libraries
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    // Android support libraries
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.1.1'
}
```

The path of the DatePickerDialog.java that Android Studio takes me to is E:\src\Android\sdk\sources\android-22\android\app\DatePickerDialog.java.  That combined with the gradle settings leads me to believe everything I'm looking at should all be API 22... I'm at total loss here.  Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That was introduced around API version 21.  If you MinSDK is lower you won't have visibility to that feature.

However I just tested this by creating a sample project from scratch setting the min/max SDK to 22 and I still don't have visibility to that method.  Potentially this is a bug in Android Studio.